Textarea scrollHeight Decreases by 2px When Typing After Deleting All Content in Blazor Application
Problem Description
I am experiencing an issue with the autoResize function for a textarea element in my Blazor application. The problem occurs when I have multiple rows of text in the textarea, delete all the content, and then start typing again. The scrollHeight of the textarea decreases by 2px each time I type a character, and it takes around 16 characters before the content height is correct again.
js debug log messages
Code Snippet
html:
<textarea id="custom-textarea" rows="1" oninput="autoResize(1, 3)">
type e.g. more than 3 rows and strg + a -> delete and type again
</textarea>

css:
textarea { line-height: 24px; width: 600px; }

Here is the relevant part of my autoResize function in:
export function autoResize(minRows, maxRows) {
    let textarea = document.getElementById("custom-textarea");

    if (textarea == null) {
        return;
    }

    // Ensure consistent box-sizing
    textarea.style.boxSizing = 'border-box';

    const lineHeight = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(textarea).lineHeight);
    textarea.style.height = "auto";

    // Calculate the height required based on the content
    const contentHeight = textarea.scrollHeight;
    const divided = contentHeight / lineHeight;
    const lines = Math.floor(divided);
    const rows = Math.min(maxRows, Math.max(minRows, lines));
    const isOverflow = lines > maxRows;

    console.log(`lineHeight: ${lineHeight}, contentHeight: ${contentHeight}, divided: ${divided}, lines: ${lines}, rows: ${rows}, isOverflow: ${isOverflow}`);

    textarea.overflowY = isOverflow ? "scroll" : "hidden";
    textarea.rows = rows;
    textarea.style.height = rows * lineHeight + "px";
    textarea.style.minHeight = lineHeight + "px";
    textarea.style.maxHeight = contentHeight + "px";
    textarea.scrollTop = textarea.scrollHeight;
}

Steps to Reproduce

Type multiple rows of text in the textarea.
Delete all the content.
Start typing again.

Observed Behavior

The scrollHeight of the textarea decreases by 2px each time a character is typed.
It takes around 16 characters before the content height is correct again.

Expected Behavior

The scrollHeight should adjust correctly without decreasing by 2px each time a character is typed.

Additional Information

The textarea element is dynamically resized based on its content using the autoResize function.
The issue seems to be related to the resetting and recalculating of the textarea height.

Question
How can I fix the autoResize function to ensure that the scrollHeight adjusts correctly without decreasing by 2px each time a character is typed after deleting all content?
What Did I Already Try

Resetting Height to 'auto': I ensured that the textarea height is reset to 'auto' before recalculating the new height to allow it to shrink if necessary.

Consistent Box-Sizing: I set the box-sizing property to border-box to include padding and border in the element's total width and height.

Line Height Calculation: I verified that the line height is being calculated correctly using window.getComputedStyle.

JavaScript Logic: I reviewed the JavaScript logic to ensure that the height is being reset and recalculated correctly.

CSS Styling: I checked the CSS styles to ensure that padding, border, and margin settings are not affecting the height calculations.

Browser Testing: I tested the behavior in different browsers to rule out browser-specific rendering quirks.


Despite these efforts, the scrollHeight of the textarea still decreases by 2px each time a character is typed after deleting all content, and it takes around 16 characters before the content height is correct again.

Please provide a proper [mre] of the issue.

It looks like this textarea.style.boxSizing = 'border-box'; is the culprit. That gets you a const contentHeight = textarea.scrollHeight;, that is two pix too low, due to the 1px border the textarea has. That commented out, and it works fine for me here: https://jsfiddle.net/utx175go/ (Had to specify a line-height, so that reading that doesn't result in NaN.)

@C3roe thanks for the quick response to my problem, but actually in my use case the textArea needs to go back to its original height (in your case height of 2 rows) when you enter lets say 3 rows full of text and delete it again. In your link I noticed that it keeps the height of the 3 rows which should not be the case for my solution.

The calculation of the number of rows appears to be off, after the bug with the height is fixed. Just comment out textarea.rows = rows; - that is superfluous to begin with, because you are explicitly setting the height of the textarea anyway. https://jsfiddle.net/5wszm3qx/

@C3roe thanks a lot for your time! You have fixed my problem :)
